# convert from british number styles to numbers only

Tags: php, formatting

i have a list of numbers that range from good ones like 51 and 102. when its over a thousand it writes it as 2,012 or 9,216. when it gets over tenthousand it writes it as 24.1k, 87.9k. when it gets over 1 million it writes as 1.4m or 142.5m.

problem is i dont know how to convert from this to readable numbers. for example, 142.5m should be 142500000.
as a first step i tried using this:

```
function cleanPrice($pris) 
{
return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $pris);
}

cleanPrice($pris);
```

it didnt go too well. i was trying to get rid of the , and . and the m and k. but got nowhere.
is there a function or something built into php that does this? i know number_format exist but it only goes one way, and that way is sadly the wrong way i want to go

Comment: Check the last character. If it's a valid suffix, multiply the number by the corresponding scale factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cleanPrice($pris) {
    $last = substr($pris, strlen($pris)-1);
    switch($last) {
        case "k": $scale = 1000; break;
        case "m": $scale = 1000000; break;
        default: $scale = 1;
    }
    return preg_replace('/[^-0-9.]/', '', $pris) * $scale;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/motkOJ)

Comment: i tried yours. it felt good. but it doesnt update any of the numbers. it finds what the last letter is. but the $pris tag is still shown as 35.2m and not 35200000. also, it doesnt seem to remove the commas and dots.

Comment: You need to echo or assign the result of the function.

Comment: like so?: $pris_ny = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $pris) * $scale; or does your forumla really work? because that last part with the return part had 2 errors in dreamweaver

Comment: I mean something like `$pris = cleanPrice($pris);`. I fixed the syntax errors when I made the demo.

Comment: im sorry, had a brainfart. this formula did everything but take into consideration for the dot (just saying if anyone uses this in a month or two). ive added to my own code so it does. and i thank you @barmar very much for your kind help!

Comment: Oops, yeah. I've fixed that now.